# Swift 3 Firebase NSString * type

Tags: ios, firebase, nsstring, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using a Firebase library call that requires a string of type `NSString *`

I'm new to swift so I don't exactly know what that means. However I have noticed that if I use a literal then it works fine, but if I use a variable then I get a thread abort.

I have

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let email = appDelegate.email
    let fullName = appDelegate.fullName
```

and I want to do this

```
    let newUser = ["name" : fullName]
    let users = self.ref.child("users")
    let currentUser = users.childByAppendingPath(email)
    currentUser.setValue(newUser)
```

but `childByAppendingPath(email)` requires type `NSString *`

Is there a way I can convert `email` into a literal/const/static ? I'm kind of lost here.

Here is `email` and `fullName` in the `AppDelegate` file

```
var fullName = String()
var email = String()
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        fullName = user.profile.name
        email = user.profile.email
```

Per recommendation of Ravi Prakash Verma (below) I tried declaring `email` and `fullName` s `NSString` but then it's complaining that the parameter should be a string?

[image]

Comment: Can you show me email and fullName in the AppDelegate file?

Comment: @DanhHuynh done

Comment: I see childByAppendingPath is deprecated in Swift 3, let change to `let currentUser = users.child(email)` or cast email to NSString `let currentUser = users.childByAppendingPath(email as NSString)`

Comment: `users.child(email)` throws an abort because `users` has no child `email` that's what the `childByAppendingPath()` is for. casting as `NSString` throws a type error `NSString is not implicitly convertible to String`

Comment: Maybe your Xcode has some problems, let try to restart, clean and build the project again! I hope it'll be worked. ☹️

Comment: Tried restarting and cleaning. NSString still throws a type error. I tried `as String` but then a sig abrt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127438/discussion-between-danh-huynh-and-kendall-weihe).

Comment: Have you tried printing `appDelegate.email` what does it shows?

Answer (score 0):

Your `fullName` and `email` are already of type `NSString *`. You can check the reference of `GIDProfileData` Class [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_profile_data#property-summary).

**Update**

You can make following change in AppDelegate.

```
var fullName: String!
var email: String!
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        fullName = user.profile.name as String
        email = user.profile.email as String
```

Comment: Check the update. Now it's complaining that it should be type `String()` ?

Comment: this throws a BAD INSTR error at the `as String` line

Comment: I tried restarting XCode and cleaning the build, but still the same issue

Comment: Try to debug your app if you are getting expected results from `user.profile.name` and `user.profile.email`.

Comment: Just refer to the authentication sample of [firebase-quickstart-ios](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios), if you are doing everything right.

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

For **Swift 2**

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let users = ref.child("users")
    let currentUser = users.childByAppendingPath(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.email!)
    print(currentUser)
```

For **Swift 3**

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let users = ref.child("users")
    let currentUser = users.child(byAppendingPath: FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.email!)
    print(currentUser)
```

And if you are using firebase 3x, **`childByAppendingPath`** is deprecated try using **`child`**

```
  let currentUser = users.child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.email!)
```

If that still doesn't work try :-

```
let currentUser = users.childByAppendingPath("\(email)")    // not preferred
```